# terraform escaping in remote exec inline kills the script

Tags: escaping, inline, quoting, terraform

I am trying to use remote-exec provisioner with inline commands to install and configure datadog_agent.  The following echo line runs just fine and appears to be quoted/escaped properly.  I cant seem to get the quoting/escaping right on the sed line.  When it uncommented, it appears like the entire inline script did not run.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
                   .
      # This line runs just fine
      "sudo sh -c \"echo 'deb https://apt.datadoghq.com/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datadog.list\"",
                   .
      # This line causes the entire inline not to run
      "sudo sh -c \"sed 's/api_key:.*/api_key: ${dd_api_key}' /etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf.example > /etc/dd-agent/datadog.conf\"",
                   .
    ]
}
```

I thought it was the * and took it out after failed attempts at escaping.  I think the * is fine (red herring).

Comment: Are you not missing a trailing slash on that sed expression? Trying `sudo sh -c "sed 's/api_key:.*/api_key: foobaz' sed_test > sed_test.out"` throws a sed error (`sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated \`s' command`). Adding the trailing slash makes it work fine. I'd suspect that adding the trailing slash to your sed expression will fix your issue here too so it's likely nothing to do with Terraform or your escaping.

Comment: That is it!  Thank you for pointing that out.  It was hard to debug, when this was incorrect none of my script actually run.  I have to find out what is processing this prior to running.  Thanks Again.